# OpenCart 2.0.2.0 fsockopen() error after update

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have recently updated OpenCart 1.5.6.4 to OpenCart 2.0.2.0.

The day I updated, Mail stopped working and I'm unable to register any user or retrieve password, even though my mail settings have not changed.

Also, I can't send any email.

Following are the mail settings I am using in opencart 2.0.2.0 :

```
Mail Protocol : SMTP
SMTP Hostname : mail.mydomain.com
SMTP Username : emailid@mydomain.com
SMTP Password : myPassword
SMTP Port     : 25
SMTP Timeout  : 10
```

Every time I try to register user or retrieve password, I get following error:

> Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/xxxxx/public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 168Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to :25 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 168Notice: Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 171

The code for `/system/library/mail.php` is below:

```
<?php
    class Mail {
    protected $to;
    protected $from;
    protected $sender;
    protected $replyto;
    protected $subject;
    protected $text;
    protected $html;
    protected $attachments = array();
    public $protocol = 'mail';
    public $smtp_hostname;
    public $smtp_username;
    public $smtp_password;
    public $smtp_port = 25;
    public $smtp_timeout = 5;
    public $newline = "\n";
    public $verp = false;
    public $parameter = '';

    public function __construct($config = array()) {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }

    public function setTo($to) {
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    public function setFrom($from) {
        $this->from = $from;
    }

    public function setSender($sender) {
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }

    public function setReplyTo($reply_to) {
        $this->replyto = $reply_to;
    }

    public function setSubject($subject) {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function setText($text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function setHtml($html) {
        $this->html = $html;
    }

    public function addAttachment($filename) {
        $this->attachments[] = $filename;
    }

    public function send() {
        if (!$this->to) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail to required!');
            exit();
        }

        if (!$this->from) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail from required!');
            exit();
        }

        if (!$this->sender) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail sender required!');
            exit();
        }

        if (!$this->subject) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail subject required!');
            exit();
        }

        if ((!$this->text) && (!$this->html)) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail message required!');
            exit();
        }

        if (!$this->replyto) {
            $this->setReplyTo($this->sender);
        }

        if (is_array($this->to)) {
            $to = implode(',', $this->to);
        } else {
            $to = $this->to;
        }

        $boundary = '----=_NextPart_' . md5(time());

        $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $this->newline;

        if ($this->protocol != 'mail') {
            $header .= 'To: ' . $to . $this->newline;
            $header .= 'Subject: ' . $this->subject . $this->newline;
        }

        $header .= 'Date: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'From: ' . $this->sender . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'Reply-To: ' . $this->replyto . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'Return-Path: ' . $this->from . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;

        if (!$this->html) {
            $message  = '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $message .= $this->text . $this->newline;
        } else {
            $message  = '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' . $boundary . '_alt"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;

            if ($this->text) {
                $message .= $this->text . $this->newline;
            } else {
                $message .= 'This is a HTML email and your email client software does not support HTML email!' . $this->newline;
            }

            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $message .= $this->html . $this->newline;
            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt--' . $this->newline;
        }

        foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
            if (file_exists($attachment)) {
                $handle = fopen($attachment, 'r');

                $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachment));

                fclose($handle);

                $message .= '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . '>' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'X-Attachment-Id: ' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
                $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
            }
        }

        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . $this->newline;

        if ($this->protocol == 'mail') {
            ini_set('sendmail_from', $this->from);

            if ($this->parameter) {
                mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter);
            } else {
                mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header);
            }
        } elseif ($this->protocol == 'smtp') {
            $tls = substr($this->smtp_hostname, 0, 3) == 'tls';
            $hostname = $tls ? substr($this->smtp_hostname, 6) : $this->smtp_hostname;

            $handle = fsockopen($hostname, $this->smtp_port, $errno, $errstr, $this->smtp_timeout);

            if (!$handle) {
                trigger_error('Error: ' . $errstr . ' (' . $errno . ')');
                exit();
            } else {
                if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                    socket_set_timeout($handle, $this->smtp_timeout, 0);
                }

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                if ($tls) {
                    fputs($handle, 'STARTTLS' . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 220) {
                        trigger_error('Error: STARTTLS not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }

                    stream_socket_enable_crypto($handle, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
                }

                if (!empty($this->smtp_username)  && !empty($this->smtp_password)) {
                    fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                        trigger_error('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }

                    fputs($handle, 'AUTH LOGIN' . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                        trigger_error('Error: AUTH LOGIN not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }

                    fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                        trigger_error('Error: Username not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }

                    fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 235) {
                        trigger_error('Error: Password not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    fputs($handle, 'HELO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                        trigger_error('Error: HELO not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }
                }

                if ($this->verp) {
                    fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>XVERP' . "\r\n");
                } else {
                    fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>' . "\r\n");
                }

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: MAIL FROM not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                if (!is_array($this->to)) {
                    fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $this->to . '>' . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                        trigger_error('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach ($this->to as $recipient) {
                        fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $recipient . '>' . "\r\n");

                        $reply = '';

                        while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                            $reply .= $line;

                            if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                            trigger_error('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                            exit();
                        }
                    }
                }

                fputs($handle, 'DATA' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 354) {
                    trigger_error('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                // According to rfc 821 we should not send more than 1000 including the CRLF
                $message = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $header . $message);
                $message = str_replace("\r", "\n", $message);

                $lines = explode("\n", $message);

                foreach ($lines as $line) {
                    $results = str_split($line, 998);

                    foreach ($results as $result) {
                        if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                            fputs($handle, $result . "\r\n");
                        } else {
                            fputs($handle, str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $result) . "\r\n");
                        }
                    }
                }

                fputs($handle, '.' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                fputs($handle, 'QUIT' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 221) {
                    trigger_error('Error: QUIT not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: You didn't try asking this in opencart forums? You might get help there faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opencart 2.0.2.0 has bug with smtp

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=22107&filter_search=smtp

this is a fix. If you configure right SMTP, it should work fine.

PROBLEM>

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_host');
```

FIX=>

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
        $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
        $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
```

Comment: Ovi : It worked for me. Although I have to restart httpd service but it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Got stuck in a new issue:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

`OK`

`<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: json in <b>/home/xxxxxx/public_html/admin/controller/sale/order.php</b> on line <b>2490</b>`


Getting above error in a pop-up every time I try to change order details of customer.

Answer (score 0):

Look like DNS issue, it can't lookup email address correctly. Anyway, try settings that works for my OpenCart 2.0.2.0 site.

My email is myemail@mydomain.com

```
Mail Protocal: Mail
Mail Parameters: -Fmyemail@mydomain.com
SMTP Hostname: mydomain.com
SMTP Username: myemail@mydomain.com
SMTP Password: myemailpassword
SMTP Port: 25
SMTP Timeout: 5
```

Remember there is a "-F" in front of my email in Mail Parameters

Comment: When I use **Mail Protocol : Mail**. It makes me wait infinite. Doesn't work for me